# VM error when trying to run React app : Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I try to run my react app I get an error message

> Can't reach the page ,

and in the console log I find this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
    at onResize (VM407:44:38)
    at HTMLDocument.setupMobileNav (VM407:71:3)
```

this is App.js code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Fixtures from './presentation/Fixtures'

function App() {

  let [leagueId,setLeagueId]=useState(0)
  let [season,setSeason]=useState(0) 
  const year=2023;

  return (
    <div >
     <div>
      <button onClick={()=>{setLeagueId(2);setSeason(year)}}>UFL</button>
      <button onClick={()=>{setLeagueId(39);setSeason(year)}}>EPL</button>
      <button onClick={()=>{setLeagueId(140);setSeason(year)}}>La Liga</button>
      <button onClick={()=>{setLeagueId(135);setSeason(year)}}>Le Calcio</button>
      <button onClick={()=>{setLeagueId(78);setSeason(year)}}>Bundesliga</button>
      <button onClick={()=>{setLeagueId(61);setSeason(year)}}>Liga Un</button>
     </div>
    {/* <Standings league={leagueId} season={season}/> */}
    <Fixtures league={leagueId} season={season}/>
    {/* <Statistics fixture={867946} teams={[52, 42]}/> */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is index.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

I use MS Edge browser, Node 20.10.0 and React 10.2.3
How to fix this error ?

Comment: The issue seems to be in the `Fixtures` component. Could you share the code of that component?